# Apex Chart Curve Smooth Not Working. thanks

Tags: charts, apexcharts

Apex Chart curve:'smooth', not working. not sure what happen, at first it was working just fine, but its just happen. any idea on what to do. do reply. thanks a lot!

Also the once the view changes like resizing the browser or showing the developer view, the chart shows correctly. but if not, the chart remains not showing.

the chart not showing if its on.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW5Un.jpg)

it only works if i remove the curve: 'smooth'.

Comment: Same thing is happening to me. Apex ignores smooth property but stepline and straight do work. That is very odd, this morning it was working.

Comment: I have not found the solution, but the issue has to do with quantity of data points, after surpassing certain size, graph automatically passes to "straight" mode.